# fetching a keys from an object javascript return undefined

Tags: javascript, object, key, undefined

I m getting a bit nervous.
Please have a look at this object fetched from Wikipedia.

[object fetched from Wikipedia API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=pageimages%7Crevisions&format=json&piprop=thumbnail%7Cname&pithumbsize=200&rvprop=content&rvparse=&titles=Lightbox_demo&redirects=)
I am mapping the data from Wiki onto my objects; in the specific, I am mapping the thumbnails.

To do that, I am extending my objects with thumbnail property.
Say, I have a node with a property "id", "name", I want to extend it with "thumbnail".

I am struggling in getting the values of keys formed by the numeric id of the page.

As example, I want to fetch the object:
...pages.6021858.thumbnail {}

And I am doing it with:

```
fetchWikipediaDecorator(wikipedia_page_id, function(data){
              var e = wikipedia_page_id,
                  f = e.toString(),
                  infoPage = data.query.pages;
              console.log('infoPage',Object.keys(infoPage)[0]);
              console.log('infoPage',infoPage.f);
              console.log('infoPage',infoPage.e);
              console.log('infoPage',infoPage[e]);
              console.log('infoPage',infoPage[f]);
              console.log('infoPage',data.query);
          });
```

I cannot understand why:

```
data.query.pages
```

is ok
but

```
data.query.pages.162510
```

is undefined.

```
console.log('infoPage',Object.keys(infoPage)[0]);
```

properly report the key '162510'
All the other cases, undefined:

```
infoPage 89513
infoPage undefined
infoPage undefined
infoPage undefined
infoPage undefined
```

I tried to call they key by number, by a string, by an array index...
I am sure i am missing smtg - could you please help and explain me the type of error?

Comment: Are `wikipedia_page_id` and the object key the same? Could you create a fiddle?  `infoPage[e]` and `infoPage[f]` should work fine unless `Object.keys(infoPage)[0]` is not the same as `wikipedia_page_id`.

Comment: Have you inspected `data.query.pages` to see if a key `162510` actually exists?

Comment: Did you try data.query.pages['162510']? ( array index with the quotes )

Comment: Tks @SebastianNette : wikipedia_page_id != Object.keys(infoPage)[0] :/
That s weird: the function should not fetch the correct page, given a wrong pageid.

The function is nested within an ajax callback.
pseudocode:

`getNodeChildren = function(..) {
$.ajax (
success: function(data) {
var children = data.children;
for c in children:
    wiki_page_id = c.id
    fetchWikipediaDecorator(wiki_page_id,callback)
   // return elements of wiki page_id from api wikipedia 
)
`
Wiki_page_id keeps the same during the cycle, yet the nested function return a different result.
Is it maybe an async issue?

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure what was the issue exactly, but I think I was making confusion between keys as an array index.

@Sebastian Nette proposed a right answer:

```
Object.keys(data.query.pages);
```

So once data are fetched, a callback like:

```
function myCallback(data) {
  var key = Object.keys(data.query.pages);
  return data.query.pages[key]
};
```

will return the object[key]